# Configure a class to support Elevated Activation

Tags: c#, com, uac

I have a class which is COM, and a want to launch an elevated COM object. I'm using LaunchElevatedCOMObject() method from VistaBridgeLibrary but all I get is the error code 0x80080017, which is "The class is not configured to support Elevated activation".

How could I configure my class to support Elevated Activation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmya, that method is marked "internal".  Unfit for public consumption.  Christoph Wille got something going, check his monologue in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssecurity/thread/5706957f-b96b-4d2b-9559-9b8b089b0bc4) for links to his blog articles and code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

http://chrison.net/UACElevationInManagedCodeGuidanceForImplementingCOMElevation.aspx